# How to turn Pandas Dataframe into JSON Formatted string?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

everyone!

I am trying to convert a Pandas Dataframe (`data1`) into specific json format string (`data2`).
How do I do that?

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ["USA", "USA", "USA", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Japan", "Japan", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"],
        "city": ["Boston", "NY", "LA", "Montreal", "Vancouver", "Calgary", "Osaka", "Kyoto","Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Hamburg", "Dresden"]
    }
)
```

........

```
data2 = [
                {"country": "USA", "city": ["Boston", "NY", "LA"]},
                {"country": "Canada", "city":  ["Montreal", "Vancouver", "Calgary'"]},
                {"country": "Japan", "city": ["Kyoto", "Osaka"]},
                {"country": "Germany", "city": ["Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Hamburg", "Dresden"]}
        ]
```

Originally `data1` is coming from SQL. After converting it to to `data2` I will pass it further to JS (via `data2_json = json.dumps(data, indent=4)`)and other Python file to be displayed in a WebApp.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This is grouped data, not just a JSON format. You need to group by `country` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = (data1.groupby('country', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)
            .to_dict('records')
      )
```

Output:

```
[{'country': 'USA', 'city': ['Boston', 'NY', 'LA']},
 {'country': 'Canada', 'city': ['Montreal', 'Vancouver', 'Calgary']},
 {'country': 'Japan', 'city': ['Osaka', 'Kyoto']},
 {'country': 'Germany', 'city': ['Berlin', 'Frankfurt', 'Hamburg', 'Dresden']}]
```

Or [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) for a json string:

```
out = (data1.groupby('country', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)
            .to_json(orient='records')
      )
```

Output:

```
'[{"country":"USA","city":["Boston","NY","LA"]},{"country":"Canada","city":["Montreal","Vancouver","Calgary"]},{"country":"Japan","city":["Osaka","Kyoto"]},{"country":"Germany","city":["Berlin","Frankfurt","Hamburg","Dresden"]}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you. They key here is `groupby` using country

```
import json
result = data1.groupby('country', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list).to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4) )
```

Comment: It works. But mozway's comment was first. I had to give the "solution" to him. Thank you, @Zee, anyway for taking time and helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the pandas dataframe by the "country" column and then convert the grouped data into JSON:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

data1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ["USA", "USA", "USA", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Japan", "Japan", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"],
        "city": ["Boston", "NY", "LA", "Montreal", "Vancouver", "Calgary", "Osaka", "Kyoto","Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Hamburg", "Dresden"]
    }
)

# Group the dataframe by "country" and aggregate "city" into a list
grouped_data = data1.groupby('country')['city'].apply(list).reset_index()

# Create the JSON in a pretty format
data2 = grouped_data.to_dict(orient='records')
data2_json = json.dumps(data2, indent=4)
print(data2_json)
```

You can remove the `indent` argument if you prefer your JSON unformatted.

Comment: It works. But mozway's comment was first. I had to give the "solution" to him. Thank you, Ada, anyway for taking time and helping.